# Are there 'Rare' or 'Very Rare' versions of Media items?

Tags: ingress

I have picked up several Media items, but all of them are Very Common variety; unlike Portal shields where I have 3 types - Common, Rare and Very Rare. Do the rarer versions of media exist, and if so how can I increase my chances of acquiring them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All my media is "Very Common" If anyone has less common media then that implies media does vary in rarity, but I've not seen any evidence of the sort and am going to declare that media hasn't been released as "Rare" or even "Common" yet.

Comment: @Alok thanks for the update, I've updated my reply given the change in information.